# Deploy java 8 application on weblogic 12c

Tags: deployment, java-8, weblogic, weblogic12c

I want to deploy a java application built with jdk8 on WebLogic 12c, and I am wondering if the WebLogic version is fully compatible with jdk8.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. WebLogic Server does fully support Oracle JDK 8